# Calculator is not showing the results on console HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple and different calculator with HTML/JS but I don't know why it doesn't appear the result on the console.

I already try different things but nothing. I'm new on this. The code is in Spanish/English

```js
function operations()
{
  var suma = document.getElementById('suma');
  var resta = document.getElementById('resta');
  var multiplicacion = document.getElementById('multiplicacion');
  var division = document.getElementById('division');
  var numero_1 = document.getElementById('num1');
  var numero_2 = document.getElementById('num2');

  switch (op.value) {
    case suma.value:
      return numero_1 + numero_2;
      break;
    case resta.value:
      return numero_1 - numero_2;
      break;
    case multiplicacion.value:
      return numero_1 * numero_2;
      break;
    case division.value:
      return numero_1 / numero_2;
      break;

    console.log(operations());
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Calculadora </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <input type = "number" id = "num1" />
      <input type = "number" id = "num2" />
    </p>
    <p> <strong> ¿Qué operación desea hacer? </strong> </p>
    <p>
      <input type = "button" value = "Sumar" id = "suma" />
      <input type = "button" value = "Restar" id = "resta" />
      <input type = "button" value = "Multiplicar" id = "multiplicacion" />
      <input type = "button" value = "Dividir" id = "division" />
    </p>
    <script src="script.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your call to `operations()` outside of the function. Even here, you'll likely need event listeners for your buttons so they call the correct operation with the right values. I don't see that `op` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code.

1. You are not using `click` event to call your function
2. You have not defined `op` in your function
3. You have added console log inside the function which means you are calling the function while in function. Which will not work.

I have fixed up everything for you! You could use an [onClick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) function to pass your `calculation` as an arguments to your function `operations` and check what is being passed with `switch` and `case`

Also, to get the `values` of the input `number` enter you need to use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) so that the `strings` are converted into number `format`.

In addition you need to make sure that values are entered in the value otherwise the click function will display `NaN`. To avoid that we can use [isNan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function to make sure there is a `value` for calculations. **If there is no value** you can just display a message *saying please enter a value*.

**Full Working Demo:**

```js
var results = document.getElementById('results');

function operations(value) {
  var numero_1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  var numero_2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
  if (!isNaN(numero_1) && !isNaN(numero_2)) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'Sumar':
        results.innerHTML = 'Results: ' + (numero_1 + numero_2);
        break;
      case 'Restar':
        results.innerHTML = 'Results: ' + (numero_1 - numero_2);
        break;
      case 'Multiplicar':
        results.innerHTML = 'Results: ' + (numero_1 * numero_2);
        break;
      case 'Dividir':
        results.innerHTML = 'Results: ' + (numero_1 / numero_2);
        break;
    }
    var final = document.getElementById('results').textContent;
    console.log(final)
  } else {
    results.innerHTML = 'Please enter value to calculate'
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Calculadora </title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <input type="number" id="num1" required />
    <input type="number" id="num2" required/>
  </p>
  <p> <strong> ¿Qué operación desea hacer? </strong> </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" onclick="operations(this.value)" value="Sumar" id="suma" />
    <input type="button" onclick="operations(this.value)" value="Restar" id="resta" />
    <input type="button" onclick="operations(this.value)" value="Multiplicar" id="multiplicacion" />
    <input type="button" onclick="operations(this.value)" value="Dividir" id="division" />
  </p>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much!  

how can I show the answer in the console as well, can you tell me please?

Comment: @maub98 I have updated my answer to add the `console.log` as well. Please check now

Answer (score 2):

```js
const suma = document.getElementById('suma');
const resta = document.getElementById('resta');
const multiplicacion = document.getElementById('multiplicacion');
const division = document.getElementById('division');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

const num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
const num2 = document.getElementById('num2');

suma.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  output.innerHTML = `${parseFloat(num1.value) + parseFloat(num2.value)}`;
});

resta.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  output.innerHTML = `${parseFloat(num1.value) - parseFloat(num2.value)}`;
});

multiplicacion.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  output.innerHTML = `${parseFloat(num1.value) * parseFloat(num2.value)}`;
});

division.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  output.innerHTML = `${parseFloat(num1.value) / parseFloat(num2.value)}`;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Calculadora </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <input type = "number" id = "num1" />
      <input type = "number" id = "num2" />
    </p>
    <p> <strong> ¿Qué operación desea hacer? </strong> </p>
    <p>
      <input type = "button" value = "Sumar" id = "suma" />
      <input type = "button" value = "Restar" id = "resta" />
      <input type = "button" value = "Multiplicar" id = "multiplicacion" />
      <input type = "button" value = "Dividir" id = "division" />
    </p>
    <p id='output' style='color: red;'></p>
    <script src="script.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

take a look at [document.write()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)